# Cannot create blank or open existing solution in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ide

I can't opened existing solution or create new, blank solution in Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate.
Few days ago everything worked fine.
I have Windows 7 x64.

[image: Error]

Any ideas, what should I do?

Comment: Assuming you didn't accidentally start a previous version of Visual Studio, this is a nasty one. Reinstalling VS is recommended. In general, check your machine for stability issues and perform a thorough disk check before you do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Till a few days ago did you open a C++ project? 
Do you have VC C++ part installed? If yes, try a repair on VS installation.